# Get text inside HTML doc element using python

Tags: python, html, html-parser

I need to get the text inside the two elements. This is HTML doc string

**string=** `"""<span class="buddyName0">adam</span></td></tr><tr><td> Dictionary_ Can you hear me now? No, I need more computer paper.  Listen, I’ll text you exactly what I need. Thanks, Luke. Talk to you later Dictionary_  How’s it going?</td></tr></table><div class="break"><br></div></div><div data-gr-conv-event="5" data-gr-conv-event-ms="1602135415343" data-gr-conv-user="ak@gmail.com"><table class="event"><tr><td><span class="timeStamp">( <span data-gr-epochtime-ms="1602135415343">2020-10-08 05:36:55 AM GMT</span>"""`

**output=** `adam Dictionary_ Can you hear me now? No, I need more computer paper.  Listen, I’ll text you exactly what I need. Thanks, Mike. Talk to you later Dictionary_  How’s it going?`

What I've tried so far,:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(string)
print (soup.find('span',{'class':'buddy'}).text)
```

> adam

Comment: Can you edit your question and fix the html so that it's well formed?

Comment: @JackFleeting  I have fixed it. I have string of HTML doc same as I have mentioned in question.

Comment: In your edited html, you have a closing `</td>',</tr>` and <'/table>` (and maybe others) without their opening tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
string_1 = soup.find('span',{'class':'buddyName0'}).text
string_2 = soup.find('tr').text

 print(str1+str2)

>>> print(str1+str2)
```

[image]